# __NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]; object cannot be nil

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am a newcomer to iOS development.  I would like to do encryption and decryption.  My question is the following: When I was running my code, the decryption was working fine in the simulator but it is not running on an iPhone device.  I get the following error message shown below:

```
[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil
```

Here is my code.  I have defined an array containing multiple strings:

```
<dictionary>
<array>
      <string>india,chennai,salem,coimbatore,krishnagiri,hosur,palghat</string>
      <string>india1,chennai1,salem1,coimbatore1,krishnagiri1,hosur1,palghat1</string>
</array>
</dictionary>

NSString *stringIndex1 = [[NSString alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *arrAthigaaramList1;
dictDecryptList=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

for(int i=0;i<[arrD_Chapter count];i++)//50 Chapter wise
        {
            stringIndex1 = [arrD_Chapter objectAtIndex:i];
            NSData  *b64DecData = [Base64 decode:stringIndex1];
            NSData *decryptedData = [[NSData alloc]init];
            decryptedData= [b64DecData AESDecryptWithPassphrase:@"mypassword"];
            NSString *decryptedStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decryptedData encoding:NSUTF32StringEncoding];

            NSLog(@"Decryped Data Base 64 encoded = %@",decryptedStr);

            [arrAthigaaramList1 addObject:decryptedStr];    
        }
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: I'm pretty sure your line `NSString *decryptedStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decryptedData encoding:NSUTF32StringEncoding];` is resulting in a `nil` string.  What's the output of your log?

Answer (score 2):

You should do the following:

```
NSString *stringIndex1 = [[NSString alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *arrAthigaaramList1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
dictDecryptList=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

for(int i=0;i<[arrD_Chapter count];i++)//50 Chapter wise
    {
        stringIndex1 = [arrD_Chapter objectAtIndex:i];
        NSData  *b64DecData = [Base64 decode:stringIndex1];
        NSData *decryptedData = [[NSData alloc]init];
        decryptedData= [b64DecData AESDecryptWithPassphrase:@"mypassword"];
        NSString *decryptedStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decryptedData encoding:NSUTF32StringEncoding];

        if (decryptedStr) {
            NSLog(@"Decryped Data Base 64 encoded = %@",decryptedStr);
            [arrAthigaaramList1 addObject:decryptedStr];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"ERROR decrypting!!!");
        }


    }
```

This would allow you do 2 things:

1) Initialise the mutable array.
2) Do not try to insert a nil string after decrypting and logging the error.

Answer (score 1):

At first look, I would say that your `NSMutableArray *arrAthigaaramList1;` is not initialized :) so you can't add item !

Change it to :

> NSMutableArray *arrAthigaaramList1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];